# Flutter app crashing when opening first time with ClassNotFoundException on Android

Tags: android, crash, flutter, classnotfoundexception

My flutter app is crashing when opening first time after installing from play store. After that it is working fine. Below is the crash report

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzccn.<init> (Unknown Source:3)
  at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver.onReceive (Unknown Source:6)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3273)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1690)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6592)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
```

Is this related to FCM messaging? The error is saying ClassNotFound but, if it is because of missing java class, then how it is working from second time onwards?

Comment: Possibly related: [Non-visual crash ClassNotFoundException #24435](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24435)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I also had this problem, just update com.google.gms: google-services: 3.2.1 to com.google.gms: google-services: 4.2.0 there in "Android\App\build.grandle" that goes the problem.

For more information: [Problem reported in github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24435)

Answer (score 1):

Just to advise, double check in android/src/main/java if the package of MainActivity class matches the attribute package in AndroidManifest.xml.